# Dovecot TLS connection handshake ChangeCipherSpec

Tags: tls, cipher-selection, rc4

I added a virtual domain to our mail server today then did a check of the Dovecot TLS connection security.  The test was done from a remote host using Thunderbird.  I captured the connection with `tcpdump` and then passed that to `ssldump`.  I also used `nmap` to verify the allowed ciphers.  That all can be found in a pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/Ap7eJB7y).

I do not understand the server->client `ChangeCipherSpec` (where it says using `TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD51 10 0.5695`) I may just be confused about how the TLS connection is setup but I have no RC4 type ciphers enabled so how (or why) is this happening?

Comment: I think there is a line break missing between `TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5` and `1 10 0.5695` there.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue myself recently. We would run `ssldump` and `openssl s_client` at the same time - `openssl` would show that the active cipher is `AES256-SHA` yet `ssldump` would still print `TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5` in its output.

**I believe I found a bug** in `ssldump`. Looking through the source code I found the following:

- The SSL handshake packets are decoded in the function `decode_ContentType_handshake()` in `ssl/ssl_enum.c:20`
- This function then calls `ssl_decode_switch(ssl,HandshakeType_decoder,t,dir,seg,data)`, where `HandshakeType_decoder` is an array of `decoder` structs\
- `ssl_decode_switch(ssl,dtable,value,dir,seg,data)` (`ssl/ssl_print.c:204`) iterates through the `dtable` array until it finds the `decoder` entry with `type == value` or `type == -1` ("not found")
- However, looking at the definition of `HandshakeType_decoder` in `ssl/ssl_enum.c:212` the array is not terminated with a `decoder` struct with `type == -1` - there's a `0` at the end
- Also, immediately following the `HandshakeType_decoder` definition is the definition of `cipher_suite_decoder` (`ssl/ssl_enum.c:266`) which is an array of the same struct `decoder`. This array contains a list of ciphers.
- This means that if the SSL handshake type is not found in `HandshakeType_decoder`, `ssl_decode_switch()` will continue searching in `cipher_suite_decoder` as it will (most probably) be in memory directly following the `HandshakeType_decoder` data
- And this turns out to be happening in my case. For some reason `decode_ContentType_handshake()` decoded the handshake packet to be of type `4` which `ssl_decode_switch()` couldn't find in the `HandshakeType_decoder`. However, by coincidence `4` is the `type` value of the `cipher_suite_decoder` entry with `name == TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5`

I run out of time to investigate this issue so I don't know why `ssldump` is trying to decode a handshake packet with invalid type. I'm however convinced that the `HandshakeType_decoder` array should be terminated with a `-1` to prevent the overrun.

Comment: @pit79 I was about to ask you if you filed a bug report.  Then I noticed that ssldump hasn't been updated since September of 2002.

Comment: I think this bug report from 2015-07-24 might have the fix: [SSLDump-Bug-Report#68](http://sourceforge.net/p/ssldump/bugs/68/). But the SSLDump project looks rather abandoned, so I don't know if anyone will implement the fix.

Comment: @SteveSether I briefly looked at the ways of submitting a bug report but haven't yet. You're quite right that SSLDump hasn't been updated in a long time - but then again, it's sort of "complete" :) I'll try to file the bug anyway and contact somebody responsible. If I can't get the fix upstream I might try contacting the Debian maintainer at least.

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff Looking at the patch in the bug report I don't think it fixes this issue. It adds/updates ciphers in the `cipher_suite_decoder` array but doesn't fix the termination of the `HandshakeType_decoder` array.

Comment: @piit79 Software is more like a living thing than it is a cake or a roast.  It's never really done, and always need to be maintained as the world around it changes.  If it's neglected, it dies, though sometimes slowly.  Anything that hasn't been updated in 13+ years is very suspect in my mind.

Comment: @SteveSether Sure, I agree. What I meant by "complete" was that dreaded state when the software has all the features the authors needed and now nobody else cares enough to continue the development :)

Comment: @piit79 Sure.  There's kind of two sets of software people in the world.  Innovators and Maintainers.  Sometimes people will take on both roles, but a lot of the time the initial innovator hands the software off to a maintainer.  It seems like that hasn't happened with ssldump.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what SSLDump is doing there.

But the client only signals support for two cipher suites and then the server picks the one labeled

```
cipherSuite         Unknown value 0xc014
```

And [this hex value decodes to](http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml):

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
```

So there is no RC4 there.

Comment: I tend to think you are right but its still a little bit disconcerting.  I guess its some kind of bug in SSLDump?

Comment: Just a bit more follow up.... you can see whats going on by running ssldump at the same time as openssl s_client -connect hostname:955    Interesting that quite a few servers print the rc4 message.  It seems to do with the original cipher chosen - but it is interesting to compare say pop.gmx.net to pop.mail.yahoo.com    gmx does not get the rc4 message, yahoo does

Comment: @TrustNoOne: how does WireShark parse that dump?

Comment: Wire shark does not make a similar pronouncement in that handshake data but I'm not sure absence in Wireshark confirms that SSLDump has a bug (but certainly seems to point that way)

Comment: Can you add a WireShark screenshot? And/or upload the raw binary dump somewhere?